# asksaveasfile dialog in python

Tags: python, file, tkinter, dialog, save

Okay, so i am developping a DnD app, and i want to save character sheets using the filedialog.asksaveasfile() command.

Here's the code:

```
def save(self):
    file_=filedialog.asksaveasfile(parent=self, mode="w",title=\
"Save your Character Sheet",defaultextension=".dndcs",filetypes=[("Character Sheets", ".dndcs"), ("All Files", ".*")])
    #file_= open(str(saveName),"w")
    string=""
    list_vars=[self.player,self.character, self.dm,self.str,self.int,self.wis,self.dex,self.con,self.cha,self.JPpoison,\
               self.JPwands,self.JPparalysis,self.JPbreath,self.JPspell,self.class_,self.race,self.align,self.AC,self.HP,self.maxHP,self.XPtotal]
    for i in range(len(list_vars)):
        string=str(list_vars[i].get())+"\n"
        print(string)
    file_.write(string)
    file_.close()
```

It doesn't return any kind of exception, but when i try to open the file, using an editor, all i see is a 0 on the first line.

What goes wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

So after numerous tries to fix that, i noticed i made a small mistake.
Indeed, it's not :ù

```
string=str(list_vars[i].get())+"\n"
```

But :

```
string+=str(list_vars[i].get())+"\n"
```

Apart from that, this code works, feel free to use it at will.

Comment: You could probably also use `mode="a"` in `asksaveasfile`, to append everything you write to the end of the file. You should then move the `file_.write(string)` to inside the for loop.

Comment: Good. Nice job on finding the solution. Self-Answers are the best for Stack Overflow.